# GridView + Dynamic Columns + PopupExtender + CheckBoxList

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkboxlist, popupcontrolextender

I have a gridview with x dynamic columns. Each column contains either a DropDownList OR  a TextBox, a CheckBoxList, and a PopUpControlExtender.

The problem is that when I do postback I have to redraw my dynamic columns and refill my lists.  But, when I refill the CheckBoxList, the other columns' DropDownBoxes are redrawn on the next line
http://i948.photobucket.com/albums/ad328/TamarChaver/messeduptable3.png

If I click on the PopUpControlExtender's TextBox, the DropDownLists from that line are redrawn, but the rest are still messed up

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it (accidentally).  I set panel1.Style["display"] = "none" and the issue resolved itself.